# How do I set the GridView RowHeaderColumn to a TemplateField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I have a standard ASP.NET `GridView` and I'd like the first column (a `emplateField`) to be rendered as `<th>`, or in ASP.NET terms, I'd like to set it to the `GridView` `RowHeaderColumn` property. But that property is looking for the name of a `DataItem` (from a `BoundColumn`).

How can I render my TemplateField with `<th>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a workaround for this. I am not sure if this code has anything to do with good ASP.NET practices, but it does the trick:

```
public class FirstColumnHeaderGridView : GridView
{
    protected override void InitializeRow(GridViewRow row, DataControlField[] fields)
    {
        DataControlFieldCell cell = new DataControlFieldHeaderCell(fields[0]);
        DataControlCellType header = DataControlCellType.DataCell;

        fields[0].InitializeCell(cell, header, row.RowState, row.RowIndex);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);


        DataControlField[] newFields = new DataControlField[fields.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 1; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            newFields[i - 1] = fields[i];
        }

        base.InitializeRow(row, newFields);
    }
}
```

Let me explain what is going on here. We are creating a special type of `GridView`, that will render its first column using `<th>` tags no matter how this column is created. For this we are overriding the `InitializeRow` method. This method basically configures cells for the row. We are handling the first cell, and let standard `GridView` take care of the rest.

The configuration we are applying to the cell is fully taken from the `GridView` implementation and is enough for the cell to be rendered with `<th>` tag instead of `<td>`.

After that workaround the usage is absolutely standard - register our class as a server control and use it as usual `GridView`:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="WebApplication1" Namespace="WebApplication1" TagPrefix="wa1" %>
...
<wa1:FirstColumnHeaderGridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                Will be inside th
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                Will be inside td
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</wa1:FirstColumnHeaderGridView>
```

Comment: Wow. I'm impressed! Great workaround! I actually diverted my efforts and cut apart some javascript that was reading my grid and played that angle. However, I tried your code, and it worked! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Código" ItemStyle-Width="9%">
      <HeaderTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text="CodigoSAP"></asp:Label>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCodigoSAP" Text='<%# Bind("CodigoSAP") %>'>                  </asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>                                    
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm almost sure I'm getting the wrong idea, what do you say?

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. Please see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowheadercolumn.aspx

Comment: There is a note in that article: *This property works only with bound fields. It does not work with template fields*.

Comment: Definetively you can not do it with a templatefield. Do you need it to render as th or you just want it to look like a th?

Comment: I saw that. Hoping there was a way around.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but we needed to set `scope="row"` in a middle column, not the first. To make it generic, in a derived `GridView` class I added the following property (similar to the GridView's built-in `RowHeaderColumn` property):

```
public int? RowHeaderColumnIndex
{
    get { return (int?)ViewState["RowHeaderColumnIndex"]; }
    set { ViewState["RowHeaderColumnIndex"] = value; }
}
```

Then set the scope:

```
protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && RowHeaderColumnIndex.HasValue)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[RowHeaderColumnIndex.Value].Attributes["scope"] = "row";
    }
}
```

When you place your custom grid just set `RowHeaderColumnIndex="0"` for the first column, `"1"` for the 2nd column and so on.